# Задать параметры поиска элемента xPath php

Tags: php, xpath

Здравствуйте.

Есть такой тег:

```
<div data-id-1="name1" data-id-2="name2" data-id-3="name3">text</div>
```

Поиск по 1 атрибуту делается так `//div[@data-id-1]`. А как найти элемент указав в поиске не 1 атрибут, а сразу несколько? К примеру чтоб нашла элемент у которого эти атрибуты: `data-id-1`, `data-id-2`, `data-id-3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.//div[@data-id-1][@data-id-2][@data-id-3]
```

Ну и есть необходимо с конкретными значениями, то:

```
.//div[@data-id-1="name1"][@data-id-2="name2"][@data-id-3="name3"]
```